# Should I delete my question if it is closed

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I posted a question a while back which was very specific (copy and pasted a lot of code and it was actually nothing anyone else could sort out). Should I delete that post as it is absolutely no use to the community or should I keep it as there were a few comments about debugging in PHP. Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 5):

Just because a question is closed, doesn't mean that it should be deleted.  There's a reason why we have **both** a closed **and** a deleted state.  A question is closed if we think that you can edit or change it into being a passable question.

A deleted question is a question that was asked in error, or is otherwise not redeemable.

If you feel like you're nearing a question ban, then you should avoid deleting your question, because the algorithm that decides whether you're question banned holds deleted questions against you.

Whether or not you delete your old unanswered question is ultimately your prerogative.  If you feel like you've asked your question in error than go ahead and delete it if you want.  Just be careful that you're not brushing up on a question ban.

Comment: Hey @sam!  I just deleted one of my own questions (it was too obscure, and pointless, and had zero activity). In fact ....... **should I also close it** (or I should say, vote to close it?)  What do you think?  Cheers!